# Improving a bash script with python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

How would I make the following less redundant? That is, is there a way to combine the two almost-identical statements into one?

```
FULFILLMENT="/Users/david/Desktop/pds" # "/Volumes/FulfilmentArray/"
ARCH1="/Users/david/Desktop/etc" # "/Volumes/Arch_01/"

FILE="/tmp/files.txt"

# find all the paths and print them to a file
sudo find $FULFILLMENT -ls | python -c '
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    r = line.strip("\n").split(None, 10)
    fn = r.pop()
    print ",".join(r) + ",\"" + fn.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
' > $FILE &&

sudo find $ARCH1 -ls | python -c '
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    r = line.strip("\n").split(None, 10)
    fn = r.pop()
    print ",".join(r) + ",\"" + fn.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
' >> $FILE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find can go through multiple directories in a single command:

```
FULFILLMENT="/Users/david/Desktop/pds" # "/Volumes/FulfilmentArray/"
ARCH1="/Users/david/Desktop/etc" # "/Volumes/Arch_01/"

FILE="/tmp/files.txt"

# find all the paths and print them to a file
sudo find "$FULFILLMENT" "$ARCH1" -ls | python -c '
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    r = line.strip("\n").split(None, 10)
    fn = r.pop()
    print ",".join(r) + ",\"" + fn.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
' > $FILE
```

Comment: Thanks, and this will do a recursive find on all the subdirectories in the main directory as well?

Comment: Yes, it will go through every dir under $FULFILLMENT and $ARCH1

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
cmd='
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    r = line.strip("\n").split(None, 10)
    fn = r.pop()
    print ",".join(r) + ",\"" + fn.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\""
'
sudo find $FULFILLMENT -ls | python -c "$cmd" >> $FILE
sudo find $ARCH1 -ls | python -c "$cmd" >> $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the output of the following is slightly different, I suspect you would be happier with:

```
FULFILLMENT=/Users/david/Desktop/pds
ARCH1=/Users/david/Desktop/etc
exec > /tmp/files.txt

find $FULFILLMENT $ARCH1 -exec stat -c '%i,%b,%A,%h,%U,%G,%y,%n' {} \;
```

The format of the date is different, and `stat` may report a different blocksize if you are not invoking `find` with POSIXLY_CORRECT.  This does not attempt to escape quotes in the filename nor to put the filename in quotes since you are clearly not worried about filenames which may contain a comma, so we can assume the output can be parsed reliably as csv and not worry about the quotes.